# Laravel routing not working, How to fix it?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

layout.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Learning Laravel With Tut.</title>
</head>
<body>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
   @yield('main')
</body>
</html>
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('main')
<h1>Welcome to my First Blog with Laravel.</h1>
<p>Welcome to my First Blog with Laravel.Welcome to my First Blog with Laravel.Welcome to my First Blog wi</p>

@stop
```

about.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('main')
<h1>About This Blog.</h1>
<p>Welcome to my First Blog with Laravel.Welcome to my First Blog with Laravel.Welcome to my First Blog wi</p>
@stop
```

contact.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('main')
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<p>Welcome to my First Blog with Laravel.Welcome to my First Blog with Laravel.Welcome to my First Blog wi</p>

@stop
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
  return View::make('index');

});
Route::get('about', function()
{
  return View::make('about');

});
Route::get('contact', function()
{
  return View::make('contact');

});
```

there's my codes I'm newbies with Laravel i was tried to create a a simple layout with Laravel Blade but unfortunetly when I'm clicking on my 'Contact Us', 'About us' page's it's not redirecting on following urls and saying not found anythings ! I didn't understood what's the wrong with following codes, Please help me
Sorry for bad English, and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the app showing? Only blank pages and nog debug messages? If that's the case change your debug settings in `app/config/app.php` to true so that it shows what is going on!

Comment: Here is some snapshot of my problems:  [Snap1](http://imgur.com/FKlCYE3)   [Snap2](http://imgur.com/tPBWzGz) [Snap3](http://imgur.com/OJD6a2T) [Snap4](http://imgur.com/TVukANR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
Route::get('/about', function()
{
  return View::make('about');

});
Route::get('/contact', function()
{
  return View::make('contact');

});
```

With thew "/" character.

Or better:

```
{{HTML::link('about', 'About me')}}
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can do as follow:

**ROUTE:**

```
Route::get('usuarios', array("before" => "inicio", function() {
    return View::make('usuarios/lista'); /*The file lista.blade.php must exist in the "usuarios" directory, the "usuarios" directory must exist in the "view" directory.*/
}));
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="/usuarios">Usuarios</a>
```

Try it. That works for me.

If that doesn't work for you: maybe your error be in the Apache configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_app/public
    <Directory /var/www/my_app/public>
        # This relaxes Apache security settings.
        AllowOverride all
        # MultiViews must be turned off.
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        #Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for help me but i want to know what is the wrong with these codes ? And i want to solve this problem with that way just by routing and don't want ot use blade function for routing, Pleas help me ? and if possible then find out all of bug.

Comment: I don't think which this is a bug. Laravel need the full path; blade use that... (you should use blade; is amazing) ¡Un saludo! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for contribution Dear bro But I'm really in much tension about this problem I can't solved it yet ! :(

Comment: I'm Trying to change my virtual host after completed all of the steps I think I've compelted but I can't make virtual host also, But my laravel public path is now working as 'localhost'  but I've set it something different like 'mydev.test' or like that but it's not working Can you help me about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the url class to create urls:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('about') }}">About</a>
```

URL will set the correct path from your document root.

Docs [here](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_to)

Comment: Thanks for help me but i want to know what is the wrong with these codes ? And i want to solve this problem with that way just by routing and don't want ot use blade function for routing, Pleas help me ? and if possible then find out all of bug.

Comment: It's not a bug, Laravel just need the full path from the document root, If you do not want to use blade just add the full url: `<a href="http://yoursite.com/about">About</a>`